# Original date of publication in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, datetime

I am using a bibliography that contains items with the original date of publication, as well as the modern reprint.

A typical entry, for instance is:

```
@book{Mill1965,
  author = {Mill, John Stuart},
  Location = {London},
  Publisher = {Longmans},
  Title = {A System of Logic, Ratiocinative and Inductive},
  Subtitle = {Being a Connected View of the Principles of Evidence and the Methods of Scientific Investigation},
  Year = {1965 [1843]}}
```

And the typeset bibliographic entry goes like this:

```
Mill, J.S. (1965 [1843]). A System of Logic, Ratiocinative and Inductive. Being a Connected View of the Principles of Evidence and the Methods of Scientific Investigation. London: Longmans.
```

The result of a cite command (`\cite{Mill1965}`) is:

```
Mill 1965 [1843]
```

I'm loading `biblatex` with the following options:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
```

How can I adapt the default `biblatex` styles to actively use the `origdate` field, in order to show that value in the biblography ending?

Comment: What is wrong with using `origdate`?

Comment: @JosephWright that it does not appear in the bibliography. (The `biblatex` manual says of this field that it is  "not used by the standard bibliography styles.")

Comment: Well no, it does not appear but it is available. The standard styles simply don't have 'built in' abilities for two separate dates. I would suggest using the `origdate` field then adapting one of the standard styles to use this: perhaps edit your question to focus on this.

Comment: You might find the 'authordate' style of `biblatex-chicago` suited to your needs.  It offers four different possibilities with regard to the date-and-origdate issue (based on Chicago's evolving views on the matter).

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55859/getting-origyear-to-work-in-biblatex

Answer (score 11):

Following `lockstep`'s answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55859/getting-origyear-to-work-in-biblatex), this code works alright for me.

```
\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}{%
  }{%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printtext[brackets]{\printorigdate}%
  }%
}
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if my `verbose`-style solution would work out of the box also for `authoryear` styles.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution without a macro could look like this

```
@book{Conrad_07,
    Address = {London},
    Author = {Joseph Conrad},
    Publisher = {Penguin},
    Title = {The Secret Agent - A Simple Tale},
    Year = {{1907/1994}}
}
```

Conrad, J. (1907/1994). The Secret Agent - A Simple Tale. Penguin, London.

Comment: If you use Biber as backend (as one probably should nowadays when one uses `biblatex`) this will probably not sort as expected.