# LaTeX using Zotero references: include original publication date using Chicago author-date in footnotes

Tags: biblatex, zotero

Chicago Author-Date requires the original publication to be indicated like so: `Smith [2008] 2020`, for a book that was first published in 2008, but I'm referencing a version from 2020.

I put that into the field "Extra" in Zotero, as instructed in this thread: https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/94398/include-original-date-of-publication-in-citation

I know this works from Zotero's end because if I input a reference into LibreOffice Writer, it does precisely the right thing.

How do I do this in LaTeX so I can convert it into PDF?

Thanks!

This is an example:

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{float}
\normalem
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\graphicspath{{"/home/me/Documents/Project/3 Things/Images/"}{}}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{titling}
\author{My Name}
\title{My Title}

% HEADINGS & SECTIONS%
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries\singlespacing}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\clearpage\setcounter{footnote}{0} }


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@schapter}{\setcounter{footnote}{0}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{\setcounter{footnote}{0}}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}

% CITATION

% Load BibLaTeX and set the style to Author-Year
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

% Tell BibLaTeX to use the file `example.bib` for the bibliography database
\addbibresource{/home/me/Documents/Zotero/Library.bib}  




% FOOTNOTES%
\usepackage[hang, flushmargin,splitrule,multiple]{footmisc}

\makeatletter%%
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{%
    \ifFN@hangfoot
    \bgroup}%
{%
    \ifFN@hangfoot
    \bgroup\def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\normalfont\@thefnmark.}}}{}{}%
% %%%
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{%
    \ifdim\footnotemargin>\z@
    \hb@xt@ \footnotemargin{\hss\@makefnmark}}%
{%
    \ifdim\footnotemargin>\z@
    \hb@xt@ \footnotemargin{\@makefnmark\hss}}{}{}%
\makeatother

\setlength{\footnotemargin}{1.25em} % Between marker and text
\setlength{\skip\footins}{1\baselineskip} % Between main text and note rule
\setlength{\footnotesep}{\skip\footins} % Between footnotes [= previous]

\renewcommand{\hangfootparskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparindent}{1em}

%%

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
%\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
%\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
    %  \usepackage[]{microtype}
    %  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
    %}{}
%\makeatletter
%\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
    %  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
        %    \usepackage{parskip}
        %  }{% else
        %    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
        %    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
    %}{% if KOMA class
    %  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
%\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
    hidelinks,
    pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
%\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
%\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
    %  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}


% SECTION NUMBERING %
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering

% Fake Sections that don't appear in the TOC or as Headers %
\newcommand{\fakesection}[1]{%
    \par\refstepcounter{section}% Increase section counter
    \sectionmark{#1}% Add section mark (header)
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}% Add section to ToC
    % Add more content here, if needed.
}



%% FANCY HEADER %%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf[]{}
\fancyhead[R]{lastname \thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{}

\fancyfoot[]{}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\usepackage{setspace}
%\doublespacing
\newlength\FHoffset
\setlength\FHoffset{1cm}
\fancyheadoffset{\FHoffset}



\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\par\singlespacing\small}


\setlength{\parindent}{5em}



% START DOCUMENT %
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
    $body$ 
    
    \footcite{Hume1896Treatise}
    
\printbibliography
\end{document}
\makeatother
```

And this is the relevant entry in my .bib file:

```
@book{Hume1896Treatise,
  title = {A Treatise of Human Nature},
  author = {Hume, David},
  editor = {Selby-Bigge, L. A. (Lewis Amherst)},
  date = {1896},
  origdate = {1739/1740},
  publisher = {{Oxford, Clarendon press}},
  url = {http://archive.org/details/treatiseofhumann01humeuoft},
  urldate = {2022-11-26},
  abstract = {book I. Of the understanding. 1739.--book II. Of the passions. 1739.--book III. Of morals. With an appendix. Wherein some passages of the foregoing volumes are illustrated and explain'd. 1740; 31},
  editora = {{Kelly - University of Toronto}},
  editoratype = {collaborator},
  langid = {english},
  pagetotal = {746},
  keywords = {Important,Primary,Ultra Priority},
  file = {/home/Zotero/storage/LMXV657W/treatiseofhumann01humeuoft.pdf}
}
```

(Note the "origdate" variable)

I've had a look at this: [Original date of publication in Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59483/original-date-of-publication-in-biblatex)

but it doesn't work for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Chicago style, you should load `biblatex-chicago` (with the `authordate` option) and not just `biblatex` and its standard `authoryear` style (`\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}`).

In order to treat the origdate as desired you'll also need to set the option `cmsdate=both,`.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate, cmsdate=both, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Hume1896Treatise,
  title       = {A Treatise of Human Nature},
  author      = {Hume, David},
  editor      = {Selby-Bigge, Lewis Amherst},
  date        = {1896},
  origdate    = {1739/1740},
  publisher   = {Clarendon press},
  location    = {Oxford},
  url         = {http://archive.org/details/treatiseofhumann01humeuoft},
  urldate     = {2022-11-26},
  editora     = {{Kelly - University of Toronto}},
  editoratype = {collaborator},
  langid      = {english},
  pagetotal   = {746},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{Hume1896Treatise}
ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Hume [1739–40] 1896) ipsum (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998)]

---

If you want to force square brackets in citations all situations, you may want to try adding

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:bothyear+oldstyle}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ (
    test {\ifentrytype{music}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{review}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{standard}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{suppperiodical}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{video}}%
    )
    and
    togl {cms@avdate}%
  }%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:av+labelyear+extrayear}}%
  {\iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
    {\printtext[cmsyearhyper]{%
        \bibopenbracket%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
        \bibclosebracket%
        \clearfield{extradate}\clearfield{extratitleyear}%
        \addspace%
        \printorigdateextra}}% \usebibmacro{origyear+endyear}
    {\iffieldundef{origyear}% ???
      {\iftoggle{cms@ordate}%
        {}%
        {\clearfield{extradate}\clearfield{extratitleyear}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:standard+labelyear+extrayear}}%
      {\iftoggle{cms@ordate}% Added test for year field ???
        {\iffieldundef{year}%
          {\usebibmacro{cite:origfirst+labelyear+extrayear}}%
          {\printtext[cmsyearhyper]{%
              \bibopenbracket%
              \usebibmacro{cite:origfirst+labelyear+extrayear}%
              \bibclosebracket%
              \setunit{\addspace}%\addspace% ???
              \clearfield{extradate}\clearfield{extratitleyear}%
              \printdateextra}}}%\usebibmacro{year+endyear}
        {\iffieldundef{year}%
          {\usebibmacro{cite:origfirst+labelyear+extrayear}}%
          {\printtext[cmsyearhyper]{%
              \bibopenbracket%
              \clearfield{extradate}\clearfield{extratitleyear}%
              \printorigdateextra%
              % \usebibmacro{origyear+endyear}%
              \bibclosebracket%
              \addspace%
              \usebibmacro{cite:standard+labelyear+extrayear}}}}}}}}%
```

For the bibliography you need

```
\renewbibmacro*{bothyear+oldstyle}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ (
    test {\ifentrytype{music}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{review}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{standard}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{suppperiodical}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{video}}%
    )
    and
    togl {cms@avdate}%
  }%
  {\usebibmacro{av+labelyear+extrayear}}% \clearfield local to \printtext
  {\iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
    {\printtext{%
        \bibopenbracket%
        \usebibmacro{labelyear+extrayear}%
        \bibclosebracket%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \clearfield{extrayear}%
        \printorigdateextra}% \usebibmacro{origyear+endyear}
      \usebibmacro{clear+datefield}{}%
      \usebibmacro{clear+datefield}{orig}}%
    {\iffieldundef{origyear}%
      {\iftoggle{cms@ordate}%
        {}%
        {\clearfield{extradate}\clearfield{extratitleyear}}%
        \usebibmacro{standard+labelyear+extrayear}}%
      {\iftoggle{cms@ordate}% ???
        {\iffieldundef{year}%
          {\usebibmacro{origfirst+labelyear+extrayear}}%
          {\printtext{%
              \bibopenbracket%
              \usebibmacro{origfirst+labelyear+extrayear}%
              \bibclosebracket%
              \setunit*{\addspace}%
              \clearfield{extradate}\clearfield{extratitleyear}%
              \printdateextra}}}% \usebibmacro{year+endyear}
        {\iffieldundef{year}%
          {\usebibmacro{origfirst+labelyear+extrayear}}%
          {\printtext{%
              \bibopenbracket%
              \clearfield{extradate}\clearfield{extratitleyear}%
              \printorigdateextra%
              % \usebibmacro{origyear+endyear}%
              \bibclosebracket%
              \setunit*{\addspace}%
              \usebibmacro{standard+labelyear+extrayear}}}}%
        \usebibmacro{clear+datefield}{orig}%
        \usebibmacro{clear+datefield}{}}}}}%
```

In both cases we have just replaced `\bibopenparen` with `\bibopenbracket` and `\bibcloseparen` with `\bibclosebracket`.

Comment: This is almost perfect, except for me the original date is now shown in (round brackets)? How do I turn them into square ones?

Comment: I see that in the biblatex-chicago documentation it seems the default is square brackets. This only applies to parenthetical citations. As I use \footcite, how do I use square brackets as well?

Comment: @ReaderGuy42 That needs a bit of code. Please have a look at the edit.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!!